# Colorbox, how to show next and previous images as thumbs?

Tags: jquery, css, gallery, thumbnails, colorbox

I just started using colorbox for a project and I want to show the next and previous images as thumbs on the left and right hand side instead of only arrows.

Is it possible to get the next and previous through the group and display them as backgrounds in a div?

pseudo:

```
$("a.gallery").colorbox({
  $("#nextBtn").css("background-image":$(this).next-image));
});
```

A bit sloppy, but I think you get what I want, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying is wrong. If you want to add CSS you can do that either by passing it as an object (between `{` and `}`) or as single parameters divided by a comma.

Either:

```
$("a.gallery").colorbox({
    $("#nextBtn").css({"background-image":$(this).next-image});
});
```

Or

```
$("a.gallery").colorbox({
    $("#nextBtn").css("background-image",$(this).next-image);
});
```

Also `$(this).next-image` doesn't make sense.
That should be something like:

```
$(this).next('img');
```

or something like that.

Comment: forgot to update this when I solved it. I basically did what you said and should've updated this and not have so sloppy pseudo-code. I basically did an array with all 'a' tags in the div and decided next and back images from that